# [SOLVED] package compiles with catkin_make but fails with catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

rplidar_ros that compiles fine with catkin_make does not compile anymore with catkin_make_isolated

```
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rplidar_ros
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rplidar_ros'
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rplidarNode.dir/src/node.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rplidarNode.dir/sdk/src/rplidar_driver.cpp.o
[ 44%] Built target rplidarNodeClient
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rplidar_ros/src/node.cpp:37:10: fatal error: std_srvs/Empty.h: No such file or directory
 #include "std_srvs/Empty.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rplidarNode.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/rplidarNode.dir/src/node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1001: CMakeFiles/rplidarNode.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'rplidar_ros':
  Command '['/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_transport/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rplidar_ros && /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_transport/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

what am I missing there ?

- catkin_make refuses to build non homogenous packages
- catkin_make_isolated ignore other packages

how do contour this ?

thanks

[ edit : giving a try with catkin tools...and I get the same issue :-( ]

[ edit : it finaly slam's !!! yes !! thanks gvdhoorn !!!]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346426/%5Bsolved%5D-package-compiles-with-catkin_make-but-fails-with-catkin_make_isolated/) by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really a problem with CMI, but with `rpilidar_ros`.

There are a few things not entirely correct with that package's build script:

1. the build script does not make the dependency on `std_srvs` of its targets explicit
2. the build script does not resolve the dependency on `std_srvs`

re: target dependencies: as you can see in [catkin documentation/.../C++ message or service dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html), all CMake targets which depend on messages *must* add appropriate `add_dependencies(<target> ..)` lines to their build scripts. The `CMakeLists.txt` ([this one](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/blob/4f899e670bec2c9e1f26b0969f2de36d23618ef3/CMakeLists.txt)) of `rplidar_ros` doesn't do this -- not for `rplidarNode` nor for `rplidarNodeClient`.

The result could be that Catkin/CMake may decide to start building targets *before* their dependencies have been built. This obviously leads to problems, such as headers which cannot be found.

re: missing dependency: while the package manifest does state the dependency on `std_srvs` ([here](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/blob/4f899e670bec2c9e1f26b0969f2de36d23618ef3/package.xml#L14)), the build script does not. Notice [here](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/blob/4f899e670bec2c9e1f26b0969f2de36d23618ef3/CMakeLists.txt#L13-L15) how it `find_package(..)`s `roscpp`, `rosconsole` and `sensor_msgs`, but it doesn't mention `std_srvs` at all.

This causes the `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` to not contain the include path for `std_srvs`, potentially causing header lookup problems during compilation.

re: CMI vs `catkin_make`: the big difference between CMI and `catkin_make` is that the former builds all packages in isolation, while the latter essentially *merges* all `CMakeLists.txt` into a single context. The consequence is that build scripts which work with `catkin_make` may break with CMI, as dependencies between build targets exist in the single context of `catkin_make`, but no longer exist when building with CMI.

This is **not** a problem of CMI, but is caused by the build scripts of those packages being broken.

In the case of `rpilidar_ros`, you should:

1. add `std_srvs` to the `find_package(catkin ..)` call
2. add `add_dependencies(<target> ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})` for all targets

And finally: if you want to be nice, and this fixes your issue, you may want to consider submitting a PR to `Slamtec/rplidar_ros` which fixes these two issues (but seeing as there are 127 forks, I'm pretty sure someone has already fixed this, but they haven't bothered to submit a PR).

---

Edit:

> edit : giving a try with catkin tools...and I get the same issue :-(

which makes sense, as the package is broken. CMI and `catkin_tools` both build packages in complete isolation, which causes them to expose the same problems with build scripts.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-11**:\

- I added the std_srvs line and it compiles fine
- I am not sure about the second part, what do you mean for "all targets" ? how do I figure the dependencies ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-11**:
There are two targets in the `CMakeLists.txt`: `rplidarNode` and `rplidarNodeClient`.

Technically, you should add `add_dependencies(..)` lines for both of those.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-11**:
I'll have a look, I updated my question in the mean time, thanks for helping me dude, I was so desperate to make this work

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-12**:
So now that you have things working, will you update [Slamtec/rplidar_ros#26](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/issues/26) and submit a PR to contribute your fixes? That would save future users a lot of time, trying to diagnose what you had to do.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-12**:
I tried but I have a permission denied...it's the first time I push my own bug fix, I feel like a young virgin lol

(note that I am pushing on the slamtec repo, not the robopeak one)

```
git branch fix_missing_std_srvs_include
git commit -m "fix missing include when compiling in isolation"
Username for 'https://github.com': phil123456
Password for 'https://phil123456@github.com':
remote: Permission to Slamtec/rplidar_ros.git denied to phil123456.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I get the feeling I miss a step...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-12**:
This might help: [opensource.com/How to create a pull request in GitHub](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/create-pull-request-github).

You cannot just push to someone else's Github repository. That's not allowed.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-12**:
ah yes someone told me about pull requests, I'll have a look, thanks

btw how did you fire the 2 targets ? rplidarNode and rplidarNodeClient

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-12**:
wow this is so cool https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/pull/27

thanks mate

(I meant 'find' in the previous comment)